# What's the best way to say "Submit or continue to do something else"

Tags: usability

I have this form on my website:

[image]

I want to add another option, like this:

[image]

However, this is too long and might be confusing for users (Do I click submit or create auction?!)

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: if you make an auction, does it matter what the user wants ( "I want..")?

Comment: The item would not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the option for the additional action (make an auction) a secondary text link after the main button - that way the link is available and in an obvious location, but you avoid the redundancy and potential distraction of two buttons.

Clicking that text link reveals the other fields and call to action.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Designate which fields are optional and which are required. If the Optional Auction fields are filled out, make it so.

- Make sure to set clear expectations with the user.
- Optimizing the layout can give you some screen space for instruction.
- You may try a [horizontal form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)  with [help text](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-help-text).
- You might take a look at [Google Advanced Search](http://www.google.com/advanced_search) as an example.